# must always restart sql server when connecting with different client

Tags: sql-server, windows-10, sql-server-2016, ssms-2016

After a BSOD the sql server doesn't work normal anymore.
I must restart the SQL SERVER (SQLEXPRESS) service every time I'm connecting with different client (application)
e.g: When I'm connecting with the software I developed it connects, then when I connect with SSMS it can't: I must restart the sql server service to let it connect. And when I'm connecting in SSMS first, my software can't connect: I must restart the service.

Here's the error:

> ### TITLE: Connect to Server
>
> Unable to connect to .\SQLEXPRESS.
>
> ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION :
>
> The client was unable to establish a connection due to an error during
>   the connection initialization process. Common causes include attempts
>   to connect the client to an unsupported version of SQL Server, a
>   server too busy to accept new connections, or a resource limitation
>   (memory or maximum number of allowed connections) on the server.
>   (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - There is no process at
>   the other end of the channel.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 233)
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=233&LinkId=20476

---

There is no process at the other end of the pipe

Comment: Is the SQL Server service running in the service applet? Can you see `sqlsrvr.exe` in task manager?

Comment: SQL Server service runs in the service applet but I don't see sqlsrvr.exe in task manager

Comment: You might need to use 'view processes from all users' to see it.... anyway at a guess your SQL Server is corrupt and you should reinstall it. Even better find a computer that doesn't BSOD and install it on there.

Comment: Is there no more solution? because I can use SQL Server for the moment (just have to restart service every time but I can work), I don't want to reinstall it  because I'll lose all my data.

Comment: No you wont lose all your data. Just backup your databases first. I suggest you find another PC to install SQL Express on and practice restoring your databases on there. You should already be backing these databases up anyway. If you aren't you are asking for trouble, particularly on a computer that has BSOD and a possibly corrupted SQL install.

Comment: I uninstalled sql server. When I reinstall i get this error: "The MOF compiler could not connect with the WMI server. This is either because of a semantic error such as an incompatibility with the existing WMI repository or an actual error such as the failure of the WMI server to start."

Comment: You really have two options: 1. Do a clean install of your OS then install SQL Server; 2. Try things like this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f0238a20-c422-442a-aa2a-76d617bb6272/ms-sql-server-2008-not-getting-installed-properly-mof-compiler-could-not-connect-with-the-wmi?forum=sqlexpress. Basically there is some kind of corruption and the easiest way to fix it is start again - reinstall the OS. Make sure you have database backups and if possibly also get a copy of the MDF/LDF files

Comment: I think even if you spent a week patching this system and following various online guides, you'd still have some corruption somewhere. Your best bet is to find a new install. What are your options - are you able to use Azure?

Comment: I don't want to reinstall Windows. So I'll try Azure or intall sql server on other computer

Comment: Azure is usually the easiest option but it has an ongoing (small) cost. Just depends on your requirements